# How can I change the maximum upload file size in document manager in telerik editor

Tags: asp.net, ajax, telerik

I have customize the telerik editor which is build on asp.net ajax shown in image.[image]

currently the document upload size in 10.00 MB so how can i increase upload document size to 50.00 MB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the **MaxUploadFileSize** property of the document manager. Check out the documentation here...

http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/editor/functionality/dialogs/file-browser-dialogs/documents

e.g. for 50MB, set it to 52428800 (bytes)

```
<telerik:RadEditor runat="server" ID="RadEditor1">
    <DocumentManager MaxUploadFileSize="52428800" ViewPaths="~/Documents" UploadPaths="~/Documents/New" DeletePaths="~/Documents/New/Articles,~/Documents/New/News" />
</telerik:RadEditor>
```

Comment: you may also want to set the maxRequestLength attribute in the web.config file https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641(VS.71).aspx